Update record while reading DataReader
I don't understand why this code doesn't update the data table:
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) From Utilizatori where NumeUtilizator='"+ usermailtxt +"' and Parola='"+ passtxt +"'", conn);

SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (sdr.Read()) 
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

    SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("Update Utilizatori Set UltimaUtilizare = '"+ dateTime + "' where IdUtilizatori='"+sdr[0]+"' ", conn);
    cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

Here I tried making something like "last seen on dd/MM/yyyy at hh:mm", updating a data table after successfully logging in (the email is useless):
this is the data table



Idutilizatori
NumeUtilicator
Parola
EmailUtilizator
UltimaUtilizare




1
bruh
admin
muie@gmail.com
4/11/2024 12:40


2
admin
admin
asd
4/11/2024 1:12


3
NULL
NULL
NULL
4/11/2024 1:11



Basically, I want to search by UserId, and it didn't update anything. Even when I changed it to user name (NumeUtilizator), the result was the same.
SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("Update Utilizatori Set UltimaUtilizare = '"+ dateTime + "' where NumeUtilizator=@usertxt ", conn);

Not even when I tried using parameters:
SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("Update Utilizatori Set UltimaUtilizare = '"+ dateTime + "' where NumeUtilizator=@usertxt ", conn);

cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertxt", usermailtxt.Text);
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

So, how do I update by ID?

Do you have a try/catch block around this code? If yes are you sure to print/show/log any errors coming from this very unsecure and unreliable code?

@usertxt is used in the query to filter on NumeUtilizator but you are putting usermailtxt.Text in it.

How specifically does this fail?  Is an exception thrown?  If ExecuteNonQuery() runs without error, what does it return?  What is the observed runtime value of the actual query being executed and the parameter value being used?  (And why not use parameters for both values?)  What specific record(s) is it expected to update?

Try to use a profiler to see exactly what SQL statements your app is sending to the database.

Your update (even when you get it working) looks weird, what are you trying to do? And why are you using COUNT(*) to get the ID of Utilizatori. As a bonus, your query is succeptable to sql injection which might be a bad thing

Yikes, this is crazy vulnerable to sql injection. NEVER USE STRING CONCATENATION FOR QUERIES LIKE THAT! NEVER! Even for integer and date variables.

Also: that plain-text password is just as bad.

its a personal project dude i dont need to be careful of sql injections on this. i wont prank myself or whatever

Yes, but this is a sign you're gonna use same style later. Do the right thing instead of learning bad habits, it's much easier to use SQL Parameter than concating strings. Also, I'm not your dude, bro

sorry, i didnt specify who i was talking to - the comment was meant for joel, im sorry for the ambiguation man

I think @siggemannen's point is, you should not assume you know what anyones preferred form of address is and stick with their name and not use dude, man, bro, sir etc

@xpl0d: "i dont need to be careful of sql injections on this" - SQL injection is a very common source of bugs.  While it may not have been the issue this time, it's pretty counterproductive to intentionally write error-prone code while trying to correct errors in the code.  Now would be a good time to start learning about query parameters.

I think you can't use the same connection for updating, while the reader is open.
You could try using a second connection for the update or close the reader before executing the update.
Reference
This may be a duplicate to
C# While reading data with DataReader cannot update same record

If the connection string contains MultipleActiveResultSets=true; then the connection could execute another command.

Note that if the reader remains open all locks in the DB required for it are still held. If the update connection tries to update the same data it could be blocked, leading to a deadlock. Make sure you don't read the same table you update, or wait for the reader to finish.

yep it was the reader problem. thanks man

Or load the DataReader into a DataTable, and iterate that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.load?view=net-8.0

In at least one of these statements you are using the wrong value for the @usertxt parameter
SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("Update Utilizatori Set UltimaUtilizare = '"+ dateTime + "' where NumeUtilizator=@usertxt ", conn);

SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("Update Utilizatori Set UltimaUtilizare = '"+ dateTime + "' where NumeUtilizator=@usertxt ", conn);
                cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertxt", **usermailtxt.Text**);
                cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

I suggest this line
SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("Update Utilizatori Set UltimaUtilizare = @Date where NumeUtilizator=@usertxt ", conn);
                cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTime);
                cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usertxt", usertxt.Text);
                cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


Answers that still use vulnerable string concatenation are always gonna get a downvote.

@Joel Coehoorn I agree. There are multiple issues with these lines of code from xpl0d. Instead of just pointing out errors I should propose a more ideal solution. After that maybe you will bless me with an upvote.

yo man whats wrong with my code :((

@xpl0d The parameter handing. datetime should be a parameter to avoid SQL injection. Also the usertxt parameter should be populated with usertxt.Text instead of usermailtxt.Text.
